# Evaluate g'(x) in terms of $\phi$ where $\phi$ is the CDF of the $N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, integration, cumulative-distribution-functions

For the following expression could someone provide some help/suggestions of my progress please

$g(x) = \int_{-ln(x)}^{x^2} \phi(t+x)   dt     $

The question asks me to evaluate $g'(1)$ in terms of $\phi$.

I started by finding the pdf of $\phi$ as the derivative of the CDF is the pdf. So I got the following:

$g'(x) = \int_{-ln(x)}^{x^2} \frac{-(t+x)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(t+x)^2}{2})   dt $

Evaluated at $x =1$ yields :

$ \phi'(1) = \frac{-(t+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(t+1)^2}{2})      $

at $x=1$ the bounds of the integral become between 0 and 1

So I think we have the following:

$g'(1) = \int_{0}^{1} (t+1)\phi'(t+1)   dt = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{-(t+1)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{(t+1)^2}{2})   dt $

But I am pretty sure this is wrong. If someone could guide me on this I would be very grateful.

Link to question:
[http://www.math.kent.edu/~oana/math60070/InterviewProblems.pdf](http://www.math.kent.edu/%7Eoana/math60070/InterviewProblems.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to find $g'$ is to write $g(x)=\int_{x-\ln x}^{x+x^{2}} \phi (s)ds$ which gives $g'(x)=\phi(x+x^{2})(1+2x)-\phi(x-\ln x) (1-\frac 1 x)$. So $g'(1)=3\phi (2)$.

Comment: Why is adding x to both limits a valid operation?

Comment: @InvestingScientist I just made the change of variable $s=t+x$ in the integral.

Comment: @InvestingScientist First putting $x=1$ in the limts of intergation and then differentiating w.r.t. $x$ is wrong. You have put $x=1$ only after finding the derivative. So your answer is not valid.

Comment: Sorry to be clear, I found the derivative of $\phi$ wrt $x$ and then evaluated it at $x=1$ which is when I changed the limits of integration. Is that still not valid? Please see the question and I will be clearer in my procedure

Comment: You differentiated inside the integral ignoring the fact that limits of integration are functions of $x$. your first step is not correct. @InvestingScientist

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe first writing this as $g(x) = \Phi(x+x^2) - \Phi(x-\ln x)$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF ($\Phi'=\phi$) would make this a bit clearer.